# Why does the NewRelic node.js driver allows multiple application names?

Tags: node.js, newrelic

Based on [this function](https://github.com/newrelic/node-newrelic/blob/0e749104b61ffc164ce987a06af2d623f7356424/lib/config.js#L622), the node.js newrelic driver allows multiple application names. Why does it allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newrelic allows you to use up to three names per application so that you can create groupings that are meaningful to your troubleshooting and environment.

This is explained in the [node.js agents config](https://github.com/newrelic/node-newrelic/blob/master/lib/config.default.js#L7-L12)

Also in New Relic's documentation [here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/nodejs-agent/installation-configuration/nodejs-agent-configuration#app_name) and [here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/new-relic-apm/installation-configuration/naming-your-application#app-name).

Comment: How I missed this page, https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/new-relic-apm/installation-configuration/using-multiple-names-app, is insane to me. haha. Thank you for assisting when my google foo proved weak.